# HTML Image Sits On Top Of Other Controls

Tags: html, css

I want to have my background image span the entire page.  This works as it should, with the exception of it sits on top of any other control/element I may add to the page.  What do I alter in order for me to be able to have an image as a background spanning the entire page as well as add text/images on top of it?  This is my current syntax:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
  html {height:100%;}
  body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
  #bg {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
  #content {position:relative; z-index:1;}
</style>
<center>
  <div>
    <font size="90" color="red">Today Is November 3<sup>rd</sup> 2015</font>
  </div>
</center>
</head>

<body>
<div id="bg"><img src="C:\KittyKat.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="1stDay" />
<font size="30" color="red">Pic 1</font><br>    
<img src="C:\1jpg" alt="" style="width:450px;height:500px;">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then you should use `C:\KittyKat.jpg` as background image of `body` or `div`

Comment: @SyamPillai - I am not following you.  Just learning html/css so now sure on all the syntax/procedures.

Comment: The `<font>` element has been deprecated and is obsolete. It should no longer be used in real code.

Comment: @Paulie_D - what should I use in it's place?

Comment: @RedLightGreenLight Look up CSS3 font properties. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used demo images for test it. Here is working code:
Just add `z-index: -1;` to `#bg`.

```css
  html {height:100%;}
  body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
  #bg {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%;z-index:-1; height:100%;}
  #content {position:relative; z-index:10;}
```

```html
<center>
  <div>
    <font size="90" color="red">Today Is November 3<sup>rd</sup> 2015</font>
  </div>
</center>

<body>
<div id="bg">
<img src="https://www2.palomar.edu/pages/testwritingstrategies/files/2015/02/online-test-fotolia_60995176.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="1stDay" />
</div>
<font size="30" color="red">Pic 1</font><br>    
<img src="http://authentic-scandinavia.com/system/images/tours/photos/155/thumbnail.jpg?1370424008" alt="" style="width:450px;height:500px;">
```

Comment: That got it!  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I would use `z-index`. It allows you to change the order of elements. So an element with `z-index: 1;` would appear in front of an element with `z-index: 0;`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
  html {height:100%;}
  body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
  #bg {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
  #backgroundImage{z-index: -1;}
  #content {position:relative; z-index:1;}
</style>
<center>
  <div>
    <font size="90" color="red">Today Is November 3<sup>rd</sup> 2015</font>
  </div>
</center>
</head>

<body>
<div id="bg"><img src="C:\KittyKat.jpg" id="backgroundImage" width="100%" height="100%" alt="1stDay" />
<font size="30" color="red">Pic 1</font><br>    
<img src="C:\1jpg" alt="" style="width:450px;height:500px;">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This still has the background image covering anything in the div tag....the image and the text Pic 1 is hidden

Comment: Then put the z-index: -1; style directly to the image in the css. I edited my post to add the z-index: -1; to the background image instead of the div.

Comment: same result.  No background image.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting the image as a  element, have you tried setting the background-image property of the div? That should provide the effect you're looking for. Add the following rule to the CSS File.

```
#bg {
    background-image: url("C:\KittyKat.jpg");
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: Shows other elements/attributes but no background image.

Comment: @RedLightGreenLight Edited answer to meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Make the image as background of the div using css

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
  html {height:100%;}
  body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
  #bg {
    position:fixed;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    background: url('C:\KittyKat.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
  }
  #content {position:relative; z-index:1;}
</style>
<center>
  <div>
    <font size="90" color="red">Today Is November 3<sup>rd</sup> 2015</font>
  </div>
</center>
</head>

<body>
<div id="bg"></div>
<font size="30" color="red">Pic 1</font><br>    
<img src="C:\1jpg" alt="" style="width:450px;height:500px;">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This shows the text/image in the body but does not actually show the background image.

Comment: even after your edit background image is still not being displayed on my page.